# getting data from another dataframe respect to index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I want to create a column with data from another dataframe based on index.

For example, I have a dataframe below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    

df1={'id':[1,1,1,3,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'name':['a','a','a','c','e','f','g','h','i','j']}

df2 = {'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'age':[21,11,45,11,56,22,26,26,17,32], 'gender':['M','M','f','f','M','f','M','M','f','M']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df1.set_index('id', inplace = True)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
df2.set_index('id', inplace = True)
```

Using this two dataframe, I want to create a column in df1 called 'gender' and get the data from df2 based on its index. So my column 'gender' in df1 will look like this:

```
['M','M','M','f','M','f','M','M','f','M']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's very easy. Simply do:

```
df1['gender'] = df2['gender']
```

Since you already set the indexes correctly, pandas will do exactly what you want. Just try and see.

Comment: Great example for showing how index works in column assignment

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
df1.join(df2['gender'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) your `df1` and `df2` on index:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)

   name  age gender
id
1     a   21      M
1     a   21      M
1     a   21      M
3     c   45      f
5     e   56      M
6     f   22      f
7     g   26      M
8     h   26      M
9     i   17      f
10    j   32      M
```

Take note that `how` is `'inner'` by default and you can change it to `'left'` should need be.